# push elements of each object inside each object inside another array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, one is my original one called `data` which consists of :

```
const datas = [
  {
    name: 'core Test',
    item: [
      {
        name: 'test/core/core.js',
        item: "item1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'users Test',
    item: [
      {
        name: 'test/users/user.js',
        item: "item2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And i have another array called `replace`, which i'm trying to push each of its elements inside my original one, inside the

```
const replace = [
  {
    type: "test1",
    number: "1",
  },
  {
    type: "test2",
    number: "2",
  }
]
```

Here is my code :

```
const transformedData = datas.map(data => {
  data.item = data.item.map(x => ({
    name: x.name,
    type: replace.map(y=>{return y;})
  }))
  return data
})
```

The output i get :

```
[
  {
    "name": "core Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "test/core/core.js",
        "type": [
          { "type": "test1", "number": "1" },
          { "type": "test2", "number": "2" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "users Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "test/users/user.js",
        "type": [
          { "type": "test1", "number": "1" },
          { "type": "test2", "number": "2" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output i want :

```
[
  {
    "name": "core Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "test/core/core.js",
        "type": { "type": "test1", "number": "1" }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "users Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "test/users/user.js",
        "type": { "type": "test2", "number": "2" }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're mapping all the way through the replace array every single time for each time you're inside of a value inside of datas. Instead you want to keep track of the index with your original map so then you only have one instance each time.

Try something like:

```
const transformedData = datas.map((data, index) => {
  data.item = data.item.map(x => ({
    name: x.name,
    type: replace[index]
  }))
  return data;
});
```